# How do I pass external source code to a Thread in java?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

I mean i need  to pass the source code as input to a threads  and let the thread compile and run the source code while it's already running ?

how could i pass a source code to map function in the mapperWordCount class , while the code of whole project is running , my program needs to take mapper and reducer code from scanner , and the code must be placed inside the map function , and reduce function, you can take a look for the code

by thread i mean not the main thread of java program .

```
class mapper extends Thread{

    // some code 

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mapper.map(bucket,reader);
    }
}
```

```
class mapperWordCount implement Mapper{
    public void map ( Bucket bucket , Reader reader){
        // code for word count mapper , this code must be entered by scanner as input , and compiled and run while the project is running 
    }
}
```

```
class reducer extends Thread{

    // some code 

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Reducer.reduce(bucket,reader);
    }
}
```

```
class reducerWordCount implement Reducer {
    public void reduce ( Bucket bucket , MapOfKeysAndLists keyListOfKeysAndValues){
        // code for reducer , this code must be entered by scanner as input , and compiled and run while the project is running 
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you had a look at [JavaCompiler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) API?

Comment: So are you saying you want to compile the code at runtime, hope it is successful, then somehow force the class loader to load it? Who in his right mind would want to do that?

Comment: @jbx yes, it's a ClassLoader ;) Now I wonder though: what if you *could* generate a `.class` file in one of the classpath directory? I'm guessing that could work (depending on the ClassLoader though...)

Comment: Are you aware that most Java installations only have a JRE and no compiler? People stopped writing self-modifying applications in the 1960s.

Comment: A *big* problem you'll have is that you can't reuse class names so you won't be able to free the memory from each compilation, eventually ending up in OOME.

Comment: @neonv do you ask questions and then don't care anymore? Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

A big warning first: you *must* be sure of where the code you want to compile comes from, as that creates a *huge* potential for, well, **code injection**.

Another warning: if you compile classes, **you can't reuse the same class name over and over** so your ClassLoader will eventually eat up all of your RAM before OOME! That reason alone should make you find another way of doing that! *Edit*: since Java 8, there is no more **PermGen space** (where class metadata were stored) but a **Metaspace**. One of the difference being Metaspace is garbage-collected, when PermGen wasn't; so it should reduce the potential for OOME.

If you're just looking for a way to add a more dynamic configuration to your program, I would strongly suggest you look at [ScriptEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html), which supports ECMAScript (very close to JavaScript) out-of-the-box (if you use Oracle's HotSpot JVM at least). It will save you the overhead of writing your own ClassLoader and compiling code.

That said, if you still want to continue in that direction, I'm just guessing here to give to a headstart, but you'll probably have to compile a file through a [JavaCompiler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) object and inject the content of the [compilation result](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/SimpleJavaFileObject.html) into a [ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html).

If I had a computer to test, I would try something like:

```
Files[] files = ... ; // input for first compilation task
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(files));
compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, compilationUnits).call().get(); // Compile the class and wait for it to finish
Class<?> cls = null;
for (JavaFileObject compiledClass : compilationUnits) {
    if (compiledClass.getKind() != Kind.CLASS)
        continue;
    int n;
    byte[] classData;
    try (InputStream is = compiledClass.openInputStream()) {
        classData = new byte[1024]; // DO A PROPER FULL READ HERE!
        n = is.read(classData);
    } // catch Exceptions here
    cls = myClassLoader.defineClass(className, classData, 0, n);
    break;
}
if (cls != null) {
    // Now, cls.newInstance() etc.
}
```

Apart from that being a complete try in the dark, you'll also have to define your own ClassLoader, as the [`defineClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass(java.lang.String,%20byte[],%20int,%20int)) method is protected.

Alternatively, you could also spawn a call to `javac` using [`Runtime.exec()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) and reading bytecode bytes directly from the generated `.class`, or even maybe generate it directly into the classpath.

Comment: If you create a new `ClassLoader` and then throw it away when done with it, the OOME problem shouldn't occur.

Comment: @Slaw you mean when it's garbage-collected? I'm not sure it would release loaded classes metadata. Before Java 8 it won't (permgen not GC'd). From Java 8, maybe...

Comment: Interesting. Looks like permgen was removed in Java 8 and was replaced with metaspace (at least for HotSpot). From what I can tell, it seems metaspace will GC the loaders/classes when needed (helped a lot by configuring memory limits); even permgen should if configured correctly. Of course, you have to make sure all references are removed (and avoid class loader leaks), whether using permgen or metaspace.

Comment: @Slaw yes, it sounds like a lot of work for questionable use (if the OP dares to enlight us with his use-case...)